# Push HTML5 Canvas Inside Videojs

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video, video.js

I've created a **canvas element** and it **overlays the videojs element** (HTML5 Video Player). Is it possible to **push that canvas inside videojs controls**? So that the canvas changes size as we change the size of the player.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible.
You can set the `z-index` of the video div is smaller than `z-index` of the controlling canvas, so the video can be overlaid by the controller. When you change the player size as you can trigger the function which resizing the canvas.

Hope it would help!